# Aptos Bytecode / ABI to move file?

Tags: blockchain, bytecode, move-lang, aptos

I have an address with some deployed modules, is there a way for me to translate the Bytecode / ABI info to a file.move so it will be human readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the source for a Move module is included when it is published on chain. If that is the case, you can download it like this:

```
aptos move download --account 6286dfd5e2778ec069d5906cd774efdba93ab2bec71550fa69363482fbd814e7 --package other
```

See this answer for much more information on the topic: [How do I call a function in a different Move module / smart contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640493/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-a-different-move-module-smart-contract)

As for converting from bytecode to source, this is technically possible, but we have no tooling to support it today. Stay posted!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer states that decompilation is not possible. Now it is! Aptos Labs + Verichains recently released a decompiler for this purpose. The source code won't be an exact match syntactically of the original code, but it should be semantically identical.

```bash
# Install Revela. The CLI needs this separate tool to decompile the bytecode.
aptos update revela

# Download the package from on chain, in this case MoveStdlib.
aptos move download --account 0x1 --bytecode --package MoveStdlib

# Decompile!
aptos move decompile --package-path MoveStdlib/bytecode_modules
```

The output should be in `MoveStdlib/bytecode_modules`. Look for files with the `.mv.move` extension.

Learn more here: https://aptoslabs.medium.com/move-revealed-the-revela-decompiler-b206eaf48b45.